# Github gist not allgned properly

Tags: wordpress, github, gist

I am trying to embed a github gist on my blog, but once I embed it, I find that my code is completely misaligned. How do I fix it?

gist link : https://gist.github.com/sarathm09/67ec411cea3b5c213cc5.js

Screenshot :

[image]
Please help me in this.

Comment: Convert your indentation to spaces, instead of tabs.

Comment: I've tried that. I've tried converting tabs to spaces and vice versa, then changing them to 2, 4 and 8 spaces. But all produce the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Which editor are you using? Some editors offer a 'Reformat code' functionality, like phpStorm. For SublimeText there is a plugin available: https://github.com/akalongman/sublimetext-codeformatter

Answer (score 0):

You can add a formatter query at the end

```
https://gist.github.com/sarathm09/67ec411cea3b5c213cc5.js?ts=2
```

for 2 tab spaces